# Create middleware in mvc 5 (not core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, middleware

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 5 (not .NET Core) project in which I want to create a simple middleware like we do in .NET Core:

```
   public class CustomMiddleware
   {
        internal const string HeaderKey = "RelationId";

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this._next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();

            if (context.Request != null)
            {
                context.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderKey, id.ToString());
            }

            await this._next.Invoke(context);
        }
  }
```

and in the startup we can do `app.UseMiddleWare<CustomMiddleware>();`

Can we do the same in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

Comment: I would suggest reading about custom attributes that can be run before and after processing a request.  They are used in ASP.NET MVC 5 framework

Comment: I was also thinking of same. But we can't use RequestDelegate in mvc project. Do you have any idea how can I achieve the same (as pasted above) if I go with custom attribute?

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of relying on middleware. I just created an ActionFilter that does the same:

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        internal const string HeaderKey = "RelationId";
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
        {
            var relationId = Guid.NewGuid();
            if (actionContext.HttpContext.Request != null)
            {
                actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderKey, relationId.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```